# Unterschied von Eigenschaftswörtern, die auf -al und -ell enden

Tags: difference, adjective, suffix

Es gibt im Deutschen Paare von Eigenschaftswörtern mit demselben Wortstamm und den Endungen *-al* bzw. *-ell,* zum Beispiel:

- *formal* und *formell*
- *ideal* und *ideell*
- *gradual* und *graduell*
- *nominal* und *nominell*

etc.

Gibt es eine Faustregel, wie sich diese Wörter in der Bedeutung unterscheiden? Ist die Bedeutung zwischen den Wörtern eines Paares immer unterschiedlich?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Faustregel lautet, daß es keinen Unterschied gibt. Dann kommen natürlich die Ausnahmen ...

Es handelt sich hier um eine [Suffigierung mit Fremdsuffixen](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/N-To-A/Suffig.html#Anchor-Tilgung-11481). Bei einigen Paaren tritt eine der beiden Formen mit der Zeit in der Hintergrund, bei anderen durchliefen die Wörter [Bedeutungsveränderungen](https://www.uni-due.de/~lge292/trainer/trainer/seiten/s620.html) (siehe auch [das Textteam](http://www.das-textteam.de/wow-archiv.php?wow_id=47&char=F)).

Je häufiger diese Unterscheidungen benötigt werden, desto häufiger treten diese Worte auf. Eine Regel, welche Endung für was genommen wird, scheint es nicht zu geben. "[Ideell](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ideell)" bedeutet "die Idee betreffend", "[formal](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/formal)" bedeutet "die Form betreffend". Ähnliche Bedeutungserklärung, aber unterschiedliche Endungen.

Es ist also nicht verwunderlich, daß die Endungen oft verwechselt werden.